# Weak geometric lemma and Ahlfors-David regular boundary of a domain

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, geometric-measure-theory

It has been conjectured by David and Mayboroda (in the paper 'Approximation of Green functions and domains with uniformly rectifiable boundaries of all dimensions', while proving theorem 6.1 in the paper) that for n dimensional domains that are quantifiably path connected with interior Harnack chains and that have interior corkscrews (which is a quantifiable scale-invariant condition that ensures interior non-tangential accessibility), and which have (n-1) dimensional Ahlfors-David regular (ADR) boundary which also satisfies the Weak Geometric Lemma (WGL), the boundary must be uniformly rectifiable (and thus would have to satisfy the Bilateral weak geometric lemma (BWGL)).

The definitions and brief discussions on uniform rectifiability and the WGL and BWGL conditions can be found, for example, in David and Semmes's introductory two chapters in their book on uniform rectifiability. In an informal way, WGL guarantees that most (in a Carleson measure sense) points of the boundary at any given scale are close locally to an (n-1) dimensional hyperplane.

The BWGL guarantees that most (in a Carleson measure sense) points of the boundary at any given scale are close locally to an (n-1) dimensional hyperplane, such that all points of this chosen hyperplane are also locally close to points on the boundary. If I understand correctly, one controls through the BWGL the fact that at most scales around most points, there are no large gaps in the boundary, once one knows that the boundary already satisfies the WGL.

My question is whether there are examples of domains with ADR boundary that satisfies WGL, but where the boundary is not uniformly rectifiable? That would mean the additional requirements of interior Harnack chains and interior corkscrews in the question posed by David and Mayboroda would be necessary assumptions to hope to guarantee uniform rectifiability.

An obvious non-example in the plane, is the domain whose boundary is the Garnett Cantor set which has dimension one and which satisfies the ADR regularity condition, but does not satisfy WGL. Here, clearly the boundary is not rectifiable, let alone being uniformly rectifiable.

Another non-example is an unbounded domain in the plane with a boundary that is a subset of the real line which has arbitrarily large gaps in a way that violates ADR, and where again the boundary is not uniformly rectifiable.